# AUTOSAR: Obtaining Application SWC-ID and Runnable ID at runtime

Tags: embedded, autosar, automotive

This pertains to the classic platform. An on-chip accelerator that we are developing, will host software that will be requested for execution remotely by application SWC running on host processor.

An AUTOSAR complex device driver is being conceptualized in order to serve as gateway to the accelerator software. This complex device driver will receive requests from runnables of various application SWC, pass on the request to accelerator, receive response from accelerator and send it (response) back to requesting application SWC.

In order to be able to distinguish themselves uniquely, am planning to have the runnables submit their SWC-ID and Runnable ID to the complex driver as part of the request data.

Question therefore is "Can the runnables determine their SWC-ID and Runnable ID at runtime (e.g. By invoking a RTE API)"?

Alternatively, how can the complex device driver determine the credentials of a requester?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at the PortDefinedArgumentValue feature ([SoftwareComponentTemplate](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/19-11/AUTOSAR_TPS_SoftwareComponentTemplate.pdf) chapter "7.6.3 Port Defined Argument Value"). With that you can annotate an id for each port which is then passed to the runnable.